# Loading geoJson with simplestyle into leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Is there any way to load a GeoJson file with "simplestyle" (for example, created with geojsonio) directly into Leaflet, so it could use the color, stroke and other properties?
It seems that it is supported in the mapbox, but what about leaflet itself?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported out-of-the-box by Leaflet but you could write your own logic using the `pointToLayer` function of `L.GeoJSON`:

> Function that will be used for creating layers for GeoJSON points (if not specified, simple markers will be created)

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer

```
new L.GeoJSON(collection, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        // Return a custom marker
    }
});
```

In that function you have access to each feature's properties so you can return a custom marker based on them. Hope that helps, also found the following gist on github which shows a implementation which might do what you are looking for:

https://gist.github.com/tmcw/3861338

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Tried that, but for some reason the pointToLayer function is never get called, so I still see my geojson without the styles... Trying to find out what went wrong....

Comment: I ended up using style function (instead of pointToLayer). I'm just replacing the style based on feature properties. So, once again, thanks for your help, you showed me the right direction!

Comment: Excuse me, i was assuming you needed markers, rereading your question i see that i should have pointed to the style function. My bad. The pointToLayer function only works for GeoJSON point features